# Open command causes loop in function

Tags: macos

I am writing a bash script on my mac and when I call a function with the open command it gets stuck in a loop.

For example:

```bsh
function (){
   open https://www.example.com
}
```

I have tried putting some echo commands in between the open command to see what happens.

If I do the following:

```bsh
function (){
   echo "checkpoint 1"
   open https://www.example.com
   echo "checkpoint 2"
}
```

I get the following output:

```
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 1...
```

If I isolate the command outside of the function then the script behaves as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have another _function_ called `open`? Check with `functions open` or `typeset -f open` in the `zsh` shell (which is the shell I'm assuming you're using as you are using anonymous functions).  I can not reproduce the behavior that you describe.

Comment: Is your function really defined like that? It's a syntax error in `bash`. Perhaps you called the function `open` (and thus have `open()` calling itself), in which case you can use `command open` within the function. @they, from https://stackoverflow.com/q/264395, it seems that `open` is a command similar to `xdg-open`.

Comment: @rowboat Anonymous functions are allowed in `zsh`. I don't see the use of it here, but the syntax is correct for `zsh`.  I know what `open` is on macOS (I have access to macOS too). I was mostly wondering whether the anonymous function was called from within another function named `open`.

Comment: I did in fact have the function named open.
I completely overlooked this possibility. When I rename the function it now works!